# Layout Width Problems For LinearLayout within ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

First of all, I apologise if there is already an answer for this, but everything I try seems to fix one issue, and create another!

I am attempting to create a listview that looks something like this:

```
GeneralLabel1           SubListItem1 Text
 |ICON|                 SubListItem2 Text
 |ICON|                 SubListItem3 Text
-----------------------------------------
GeneralLabel2           SubListItem1 Text
 |ICON|                 SubListItem2 Text
 |ICON|                 
-----------------------------------------
GeneralLabel3           SubListItem1 Text
 |ICON|                 SubListItem2 Text
 |ICON|                 SubListItem3 Text
                        SubListItem4 Text
                        SubListItem5 Text
```

Currently, I am using a BaseAdapter to create the "GeneralLabel" view (which just contains a TextView and a LinearLayout), and then iterating through each of the SubListItems attached to it, using

```
 rootView = view;
 if (rootView == null){
     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteritem_generalitem,viewGroup,false);
 }
 LinearLayout subListItemLayout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.subListItemLayout);
 for (SubListItem item: GeneralItem.subItems){
     View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteritem_sublistitem,null);
     ((TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.subListItemField1)).setText(item.field1String);
     ((TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.subListItemField2)).setText(item.field2String);
     subListItemLayout.addView(childView);
 }
 return rootView;
```

The XML layout inflated for the `rootView` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/generalLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/avIndicator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/subListItemLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The XML layout inflated for the SubListItem rows is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/colon_separator"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/subListItemField1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/separator"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/Xercisr_Dark_Gray"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/subListItemField2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the width of both the GeneralLabel field and the SubListItem rows are variable. I need to give priority to the SubListItem rows, and display them on one line (forcing the GeneralLabel to break over multiple lines if necessary). The current solution produces the right *sort* of output, but the SubListItem rows break over multiple lines.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding single line attribute to subListItem

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

Comment: Thankyou - close, but no cigar unfortunately. I just get an ellipsis at the end of what it displays on the screen

Comment: I just realize singleLine is deprecated. Use maxLines instead to set the number of line. ' 'android:maxLines = "1"; android:scrollHorizontally = "true" // this allows horizontal scrolling android:ellipsize = "none" '